# Как получить ответ со страницы ajax и вывести его без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Учу js, выдумываю задачи, зациклилась на одной, очень хочется послушать знающий людей)) 
Есть форма с одним полем ввода - промокод. Ввожу промокод и кликаю на кнопку "Активировать промокод". Вот как выглядит форма.

```
<div class="ta-c">
    <h3 class="promo-title light">Введите свой промокод</h3>
        <form action="" class="promo-form">
        <input type="text" name="promo" id="promocod" class="promo-input" placeholder="____" maxlength="4" >
        <div class="promo-text"></div>
        <button class="button js-promo-activate" id="active_promocod">Активировать промокод</button>

    <div class="result">
        <span id="answer"> <div class="messages_promo"></div> </span>
        <span class="loader hidden"><img src="img/loader.gif" alt=""></span>
    </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Далее, пишу скрипт, отправляю в файл controllPromocod.php для проверки, есть ли этот промокод в системе или нет. Вот тут мне не очень нравится, как я все это пишу, кажется так все громоздко.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#active_promocod').click(function(){
                // собираем данные с формы
                var promocod=$('#promocod').val();
                alert(promocod);

                //                 отправляем данные
                $.ajax({
                    url: "../controllPromocod.php", // куда отправляем
                    type: "post", // метод передачи
                    dataType: "json", // тип передачи данных
                    data: { // что отправляем
                        "promocod": promocod
                    },
                    // после получения ответа сервера
                   success: function(data) {

                    $('.messages_promo').html(data.result); // выводим ответ сервера
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(".loader").addClass('hidden');
                    }, 50000) // 10 секунд
                    }

                });

            });
        });
```

Далее в файле php идет проверка

```
<?php
$msg_box = ""; // в этой переменной будем хранить сообщения формы
    $errors = array(); // контейнер для ошибок
    // проверяем корректность поля
    (isset($_POST['promocod']) AND !empty($_POST['promocod']))?'':$errors[] = "Заполните поле 'Промокод'";

    if(empty($errors))   
    {  
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM CRM_PARTNERS WHERE promocod='".$_POST['promocod']."'";
        $r = mysqli_query($mysql,$SQL);
        if(!$r) exit(mysqli_error($mysql));
        $hk=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r);

        if (isset($hk['promocod']) AND !empty($hk['promocod']))
        {

            // собираем данные из формы
            $message .= "Промокод: " . $_POST['promocod']. "<br/>";  
            $message .= "Дата и время (MSC): " . date("d.m.y H:i"); 
            send_mail($message); // отправим письмо
            $msg_box = "<span style='color: green;'>Промокод активирон!</span>";
        }
        else 
        {
            $message="Промокода нет в системе";
            $msg_box = "";
            foreach($errors as $one_error){
            $msg_box .= "<span style='color: red;'>$one_error</span><br/>";
            }
            send_mail($message); // отправим письмо


        }
    }    
         echo json_encode(array(
        'result' => $msg_box
        ));
        // функция отправки письма
            function send_mail($message){
                // почта, на которую придет письмо
                $mail_to = "test@ya.ru"; 
                // тема письма
                $subject = "Промокод";

                // заголовок письма
                $headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; // кодировка письма
                $headers .= "From: Тестовое письмо <no-reply@test.com>\r\n"; // от кого письмо

                // отправляем письмо 
                mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            }
?>
```

Что в итоге получается: 
ввожу промокод
срабатывает скрипт и отправляет промокод в файл на проверку
далее мне приходит на почту письмо, есть промокод или нет его
но на странице, где поле ввода не выводит информация, есть промокод или нет его 
страница перезагружается - ПОЧЕМУ?

Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу научиться)))

Comment: Потому что у вас кнопка перешружает форму - поставьте `type="button"` для кнопки.

Comment: $('#active_promocod').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* дальше ваш код */ });

Comment: Вау!!! я бы никогда не догадалась, что дело в type="button" !!! все получилось,перезагрузки нет. Спасибо!!!

$('#active_promocod').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* дальше ваш код */ }); – вот с этим пока не получилось, мой ответ от ajax файла пока не выводится с инфой о том, есть промокод в бд или нет, буду думать дальше)))